# Importing Http Invoker Configs into Spring Boot App

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project where I need to expose my services using REST/JSON services.  I have used Spring Boot to develop the controllers, where I then inject the services via the HTTP Invoker proxies.  The idea works since I have done it using a basic Spring 3.2 App using XML configs.  However, I am getting problems importing the HTTP Invoker proxies into the Spring Boot app.  It fails to find the relevant beans when injecting them into the controllers.

The error (basic unit test when building using Gradle):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.flashmobilecash.services.PrePaidAirtimeService za.co.flash.openapi.web.AirtimePurchaseController.airtimeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.flashmobilecash.services.PrePaidAirtimeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.flashmobilecash.services.PrePaidAirtimeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 61 more
```

The HTTP Invoker proxies is configured in a Java config:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpServicesConfig {
    @Value("${flashtp.ipaddress}")
    private String ipAddress;
    @Value("${flashtp.httpservices.port}")
    private String port;
    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setMaxConnPerRoute(60);
        builder.setMaxConnTotal(60);
        RequestConfig requestConfig =
            RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(10000)
                                  .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
                                  .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                                  .build();
        builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
        return httpClient;
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor httpClientExecutor() {
        HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor executor = 
            new HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
        executor.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        executor.setHttpClient(httpClient());
        return executor;
    }

    .....

    @Bean
    public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean prePaidAirtimeService() {
        HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean b = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
        b.setServiceInterface(PrePaidAirtimeService.class);
        b.setServiceUrl(
            "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + port +
            "/flash-http-services/remoting/prePaidAirtimeService");
        b.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(httpClientExecutor());
        return b;
    }
}
```

This config is then imported into the main application config:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HttpServicesConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "za.co.flash.openapi" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
    })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Regards

Comment: Looks like you didn't define 'PrePaidAirtimeService' as a Spring Bean.

Comment: It is accessed using the HTTP Invokers.  The actual services runs on another server.

Comment: Never worked with HTTP Invokers, so i can't help you there, but the stack trace seems to clearly state that your code can't find the Bean in question to Autowire it.

Comment: Hence my question here.  The concept works perfectly fine when used in a Spring 3.2 project with XML configs. Only difference is I am trying to do this now with Java configs in a Spring Boot app.

Comment: The problem is that the return type of your factory method is `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean`, which in turn is actually of the type `FactoryBean<Object>`. When using java config the latter is used to determine the type of the factory bean. In this case it will thus be problematic as the `PrePaidAirtimeService` isn't available. (XML is in this regard processed slightly different). What you could do is call `afterPropertiesSet()` and afterwards `getObject()` and return the result of that call.

Comment: Thanks.  My understanding was that the HTTP Invoker exposes the same interface as the real service implementation, and that Spring would look for a bean implementing or exposing the required interface specified in the service property that was autowired in the Controller.  I will investigate your suggestion.  I was though not aware that Spring handles the XML and Java configs differently.

Comment: Your suggestion of calling afterPropertiesSet() on the factory and then getObject() solved the issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This way of configuring the HTTP Invoker in Spring Java config solved the issue:

```
@Bean
public PrePaidAirtimeService prePaidAirtimeService() {
    HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean f = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    f.setServiceInterface(PrePaidAirtimeService.class);
    f.setServiceUrl(
        "http://" + ipAddress + ":" + port +
        "/flash-http-services/remoting/prePaidAirtimeService");
    f.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(httpClientExecutor());
    f.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (PrePaidAirtimeService) f.getObject();
}
```

Thank you @M. Deinum for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: BTW, I renamed the variable from b to f to remind me that I am actually working with a Factory.